# How to pass PayPal send invoice reminder value using c#..? (PayPal Invoicing API)

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm integrating PayPal Send Invoice Reminder through PayPal Invoicing API.

Here is my code,

sandbox url

```
var sandbox = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/";
```

notification object,

```
var notification = new Notification
{
  subject = "Payment Reminder",
  note = "This is a reminder that payment is due on " + InvoiceDueDate,
  send_to_merchant = true
};
```

Invoice Id and Generated Access Token,

```
var invoice_id = "your invoice id";
var access_token = "your generated access token";
```

PayPal Send Reminder Api needed above values for Send Reminder Task but how to get response using above values and also how to pass these values(parameters) to rest API of PayPal.

Thanks, Kaushik.

Send Reminder PayPal Example:
[image]

Comment: Does the official information say something about this?

Comment: @chade_here is link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#invoices_remind